# What is the git log pretty format placeholder that will show the same as the --source option?

Tags: git

I can use the `--source` option to show me one of the branches that each git commit listed is on, for example

```
git log --branches --author=Tim --since='February' --decorate --oneline --source
```

shows me all my commits since February and one of the branches that the commit can be reached from. Here's how the output looks for me

[image: git bash screenshot]

I'd like to add in the date do I have swapped to using the `--pretty` option:

```
git log --branches --author=Tim --since=February --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Creset %Cred%d%Creset %C(cyan)%ar%Creset : %s"
```

and the corresponding output

[image: git bash screenshot]

The pretty format placeholder `%d` adds the "ref names, like the --decorate option" (from the documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)). What is the pretty format placeholder to include the ref name by which each commit was reached, like the --source option?

Comment: BTW, instead of `%C(red)%d` put `%C(auto)%d` and you will get nicer colors like the `--decorate` ones..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the pretty format placeholder to include the ref name by which each commit was reached, like the `--source` option?

There isn't one.  The `--source` option sets a flag that [makes the revision walk add the appropriate command-line reference name to each commit the first time the commit is reached](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d1b10321b20bd2a73a5b561cfc3cf2e8051b70b/revision.c#L251-L262).  The same flag is [tested, and the saved information shown directly to a stdio stream, in `show_decorations` in `log-tree.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d1b10321b20bd2a73a5b561cfc3cf2e8051b70b/log-tree.c#L282-L293), but nothing in [pretty.c](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d1b10321b20bd2a73a5b561cfc3cf2e8051b70b/pretty.c) uses that field.

(Other code uses `->util` but for other purposes, hence the field name, `util`.  Note that it should be fairly easy to add a new format character that expands to the util field if saved, but you'd still have to set the flag.)

Comment: [No longer true, git 2.21.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54827750/239657) added `%S` (uppercase).