# Git log source in pretty format

Tags: git

Is there any way to show source while using pretty=format?

Im getting information on which track specific commit was pushed by command

```
git log --source --oneline
```

But I also need a date=short which I see cannot be used together with --oneline. But can with pretty=format. Problem is that I don't know how to show --source in pretty=format, can you help?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824916/cant-find-any-file-placeholder-for-the-git-log-pretty-format) posted 15 min ago. Related maybe? Hmmm..... not really.

Comment: Well, I have to have --source information

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at [this post](https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log). It gives a very nice exemple of a customize git log. And also an oneliner to define it with a Git alias.

To try it, you can type:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

To define it in an alias:

```
git config --global alias.lg "git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit"
```

To use it :

```
git lg
```

To check your configuration:

```
git config alias.lg
```

To remove it:

```
git config --unset alias.lg
```

---

### date=short

If you want to go further in the configuration, you should look at the [Git pretty-formats documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) (placeholders section).

**For the date you were talking about, you could change the %cr by %ad because this format respects the --date=option. So you could use --date=short as you want.**

---

### Tig

To finish there is a very powerful tool you could use if you are a command line lover like me: [Tig](https://jonas.github.io/tig/)

Answer (score 1):

This will become possible with the `--pretty=format:%S` token supported in the upcoming Git 2.21.0.

Comment: Are you sure because as said [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats). pretty-formats were last updated in 2.20.0 and there is no `--pretty=format:%S`. You are probably talking about the subject placeholder %s: `--pretty=format:%s`.

Comment: @NicolasDupouy no, I'm talking about a new placeholder which will be in 2.21.0rc0, -rc1 and -rc2. Since these haven't been released yet, the new placeholder doesn't show up in the online documentation, but you can already see it in the documentation source on the master branch.